# How to invert only one of H, S, or L?

Tags: css, css-filters

I've been using the [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) extension to Google Chrome to browse [xkcd in dark](https://userstyles.org/styles/121273/dark-xkcd). The user-style called Dark XKCD uses `filter: invert(100%);` to make the generally white images generally dark. However, `invert` messes with the colors, such as in this comic, which normally looks like this:

[image: xkcd 681]

But instead, it looks like this (snippet, as it's hard to simply save the image):

```css
img {
  max-width: 70%; /* make image easily visible for demonstration */
  filter: invert(100%);
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  -moz-filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/gravity_wells.png"/>
```

The orange becomes blue!

I found `hue-rotate`, which semi-fixes it if I apply with invert:

```css
img {
  max-width: 70%; /* make image easily visible for demonstration */
  filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg);
  -moz-filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/gravity_wells.png"/>
```

However, it fails for other comics; for example, [this one](https://xkcd.com/392/):

```css
img {
  filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg);
  -moz-filter: invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/making_rules.png"/>
```

I can now fiddle with the hue of the image or the saturation and lightness together, but maybe if I could de-couple the inversion of the saturation and lightness, I could achieve better results.

How can I invert hue, saturation, or lightness without touching the others?

Comment: You realize blue is the inverse of orange right... and red to green, and violet to yellow. I know... don't really answer your question. But seeing orange replaced with blue after invert isn't really abnormal. :)

Comment: @SOIA I know; I'm just trying to fiddle with the image to make it overall darker without affecting the colors (as much as possible). I understand `invert` inverts the color, but I want to keep the colors the same; dark mode on XKCD :-)

Comment: @Justin Did you get any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do HSL operations in filters - they're RGB only. Filters hue rotate is a (generally bad) approximation of a true hue rotation using RGB space. There are somewhat complex things you can do in filters to "color-separate" out colored areas from greys/whites, invert the separately and then recombine. But it's not a great general solution.